# closed form solution of a particular convex program

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I wish to know if there is a closed form solution of a program of the following form

$\max_w x^Tw \text{ such that } \tau_2\| w \|_2 + \tau_1 \| w \|_1 \leq 1, ~\ \tau_1, \tau_2 > 0$

When either of the $\tau$ are zero, we can obtain a closed form solution. I am unable to obtain one for arbitrary $\tau$ though.  The constraint set is a ball that looks similar to the "elastic net" penalty in statistics.

Comment: I'm nearly certain the answer is no. Closed form solutions are the exception, not the rule.

Comment: @MichaelGrant yes. I believe so too. I am wondering if there is somebody out there that a) thinks otherwise and b) can prove it.

Comment: Can you find a closed-form solution to this problem? This is a slightly modified version of the dual of your problem:
$$\begin{array}{ll}\text{minimize}&\max\{\|z_1\|_2,\|z_2\|_\infty\}\\\text{subject to}&\tau_1 z_1+\tau_2 z_2 = x\end{array}$$If you can, then it won't be hard to recover a solution to your original.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I was sick for a few days. I tried, i'm not sure i can.

Comment: No problem. It was just a thought about a potential direction to try. Like I said I doubt there is a closed-form solution here.